# Can you make :after styling dependent on the element value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to do some dynamic styling of a number input field, so I put it in a span element so I could add non-numeric characters:

```
<span class='formatter'>
    <input type='number'>0.00</input>
</span>
```

Then, in the css:

```
.formatter:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:"%";
    top: 12px;
}
```

This works, the % appears but I'd like it to appear right after the input value. So, I could use left: 200px; to push the % to the end of the input field but I'd like it to appear after the number itself, whether it's 0.00 or 100.00. Is there a way to tie the content position to the input value?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your markup is invalid: `<input>` is a [void tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element).
You probably want to use the [placeholder attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/placeholder):

```
<input placeholder="0.00%">
```

As for masking, it's not as easy as it may look. You could write your own directives but you need to consider the following:

- your input has to be `type="text"` instead of `number` if you want to display non-digits (and number related chars) in it
- when you're updating the value of the input you'll need to tap into angular's `ng-model` binding, or use a custom defined `$filter`, or a watcher to update the value in the next digest cycle

Or you could just use [angular-input-mask](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks) package, which was designed for masking inputs in angular.js:

```html
<input type="text"
       placeholder="0.00%"
       ng-model="number" 
       ui-percentage-mask="2" 
       ui-percentage-value
       ui-hide-space
>
```

---

Working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.utils.masks']);
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.number = 100;
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-input-masks/4.2.1/angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
  <input type="text"
         placeholder="0.00%"
         ng-model="number" 
         ui-percentage-mask="2" 
         ui-percentage-value
         ui-hide-space
   >
 </div>
```

The downside is that when you type `20`, because you want 2 decimals, you will need to type `2000` but it's sort of intuitive.

---

Alternatively, you could combine it with a range input, to provide a friendlier UX. I also played a bit with listeners to provide it with more of a `type="number"` feel, but you can discard that altogether:

```js
app = angular.module('app', ['ui.utils.masks']);

/* 
 * You don't really need any of the controller code below. 
 * I just fooled around binding keydown events to experiment making 
 * the input[type="text"] feel more like [type="number"].

 * If you don't want it, simply use...

app.controller('testController', () => [])

 * ... or delete it altogether and remove `ng-controller`
 * attribute from [ng-app] element.
 */

app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$element', '$timeout', function($s, $e, $t) {
  this.$onInit = function() {
    // binding $scope.number changes on up/down/pageUp/pageDb
    $e.on('keydown', 'input', (e) => {
      if ([38, 40, 33, 34].includes(e.keyCode)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if ([38, 40].includes(e.keyCode))
          $s.number += e.keyCode === 38 ? .1 : -.1;
        else
          $s.number += e.keyCode === 33 ? 1 : -1;
        $t(() => $s.$apply());
        return false;
      }
    })
  };
}]);
```

```css
input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
input-wrapper [type="text"]{ 
  font-size: 2rem;
}

input-wrapper [type="range"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - .5rem);
  left: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  transition: opacity .25s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .3, 1);
}

input-wrapper:hover [type="range"],
input-wrapper input:focus~[type="range"],
input-wrapper input:active~[type="range"],
input-wrapper [type="range"]:focus,
input-wrapper [type="range"]:active {
  opacity: 1;
}

input-wrapper [type="text"] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

p {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-input-masks/4.2.1/angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
  <input-wrapper>
    <input type="text" placeholder="0.00%" ng-model="number" ui-percentage-mask="2" ui-percentage-value ui-hide-space>
    <input type="range" ng-model="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.01">
  </input-wrapper>
  <p>Use Up/Down/pageUp/pageDn on a focused input
</div>
```

If you finding it difficult to [style the range slider cross-browser](https://css-tricks.com/custom-interactive-range-inputs/) there are quite a few packages providing styled range sliders, some of which customizable.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, and the example - very nice. I'll dig into this and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

I would abandon css :after property and write something like this:

```
<div class="formatter">
    <input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.number">0.00</input>
    <span ng-if="$ctrl.number <= 100" class="pretty_percentage">%</span>
</div>
```

Then customize `pretty_percentage` css.

Comment: A custom filter would fit nicely here as well.

Comment: @Phix I'm willing to give it a shot though I've never done it before...can you give an example of what that would look like..?

Comment: @monkeyWithAMachinegun Sure, check out [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) and report back if you run into any issues.

Comment: @Phix I tried the filter, and it sort of works...it would be a great solution if I can figure out what I'm doing wrong. These HTML elements are getting created on the fly, so I did something like (where 'elem' is the newly created input element): elem.innerHTML = '{{ '+thevalue+ ' | currency }}'. When it runs, it displays just a number value (say 100 for this example), but if I go into the browser console I can see it presented as <input type="text">$100.00</input>. So it seems like the filter got applied but I must have misconfigured something. Maybe innerHTML is the wrong value to set?

Comment: Create a new question, you can't set it with innerhtml. There are other mechanisms available.

Comment: @Phix Thanks, if you know a way to do this it would be a huge help - I opened one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241938/is-it-possible-to-apply-a-custom-filter-to-an-element-using-javascript