# Is it possible to apply a custom filter to an element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm generating a series of HTML elements from metadata, and I'm wondering if there's a way to apply a custom filter to these elements. For this example it's an input element:

```
var elem = document.createElement('input');
elem.id = "input1";
elem.setAttribute('ng-model', 'results.val');
elem.innerHTML = '{{ ' + results.val + ' | currency }}';
```

Then later in the code, it gets compiled:

```
$compile(elem)(scope)
```

Using this scheme, when results.val is 50, the input element displays just 50 on the page. However, if I look at the element in the browser console, I see the filter applied:

```
<input id='input1'>$50.00</input>
```

I feel like I'm on the right track but that I'm misconfiguring things. Assuming it's possible, can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Here is an example of what the metadata used to generate the elements looks like:

```
[{
    field: "ExampleOne",
    datatype: "enum",
    type: "select",
    description: "exampleOneType",
    format: "",
    enum: [
        0: "option1"
        1: "option2"
        2: "option3"
    ]
},
{
    field: "ExampleTwo",
    datatype: "input",
    type: "text",
    description: "exampleTwoType",
    format: "$"
}]
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're building them dynamically versus `ng-repeat`? There could be a much easier [way to tackle this](http://plnkr.co/edit/qxeXM5SefHrxeUYNRoht?p=preview).

Comment: It's a generic component, so it never knows what element/type will be included next (it's based on the metadata it loads). The id, class assignment, ng-model, etc. all gets dynamically generated. The idea was that it might look totally different depending on the metadata you have it load. Initially I thought about using templates but as I worked on it I realized my templates were basically ending up as basic elements like <select>selectOpt</select> and filling in the attributes using javascript. At that point I figured I may as well just create the element in javascript as well.

Comment: Can you post a few entries of the metadata?

Comment: I added an example of what the data object I get looks like. That example basically describes a select box with options, and an input field.